# How is the backbone and head of YOLOv8 connected?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, yolo

I have view this [image].

But `C2f` only has single output tensor.

What is the meaning of the connection between Backbone and Head in the diagram? Is it a copy of output which is also connect to the `Conv` below?

Those connection has label `80x80x256xw; Stride=8`, `40x40x512xw; Stride=16`,

What is the `Stride` means here, because for `C2f` the stride of underlay Conv network is hardcoded. There is no such parameter for it.

Can